# What does almost $\sigma$-bounded mean?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, terminology

So I came across this in a [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485892007), it says that a locally compact space $X$ is almost $\sigma$-bounded. What does this mean?

Comment: can you show the paper (by link or picture)?

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485892007

Comment: So it's around section 8, and the end of section 7

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is the right definition:
[image]
and
[image]
I simply Ctrl+F "bounded" and that popped up on page 3 and page 13.

Comment: For future research purposes, it would be better to actually type out the relevant part of the answer.

Comment: Also, this is not quite the answer as it lacks the "almost" part.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I have found the correct definition, though I see you've already typed up the answer.

Comment: Yes, I'd found it anyway and didn't know whether you were coming back.

Answer (score 1):

You will find the definition within the statement of Theorem 7 of the [linked paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485892007):

> An almost $\sigma$-bounded set is the union of a $\sigma$-bounded set
>   and a null set. A $\sigma$-bounded set is (as per the definition given in the peliminary section, compare @D.R 's answer) the union of countably many bounded sets.